# How to add SSL certificate into the jvm for java 17

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, ssl-certificate, java-17

I need to add my SSL certificate file to the JVM trust store. I have java oracle 8 and java adoptium 17 installed.

Following this [link](https://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store) I have successfully added the certificate for java 8 and can communicate using the certificate. Here is the command

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file ca.crt
```

But now I need to add this to java 17 as well. With the same command, I could not add the certificate. I found out that for java 17 the `JAVA_HOME` does not have directory `jre/lib/security` , rather it has `conf/security` directory. So i changed my command to this

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file ca.crt
```

This command generates the `cacerts` file under the `security` folder, but still, I am getting error. This same error i was getting in java 8 before adding certificate. Where I am supposed to put this `cacerts` file for java 17?

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:288) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:356) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:547) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) can be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `%JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`